# how to exclude few folder levels in the FIND command results - unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Following is the folder structure
- **home/ABCD/test1/example1/sample1/textfile.txt**

If I execute the **find** command like

```
find /home/ABCD/ -type f -print
```

I am getting the following output

```
/home/ABCD/test1/example1/sample1/textfile.txt
```

Note: **I am executing the find command from the ABCD folder**, In the results I want to exclude /home/ABCD/ folder I just want **/test1/example1/sample1/testfile.txt** as the result

How can I achieve this?

Comment: find /home/ABCD/ -printf '/%P\n'

Comment: %P - File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are executing find from `/home/ABCD/` do something like this:

```
find * -type f -print
```

Or if you are looking for files in `test1` do this:

```
find test1 -type f -print
```

Also with `-maxdepth N` you can limit the recursion in find

If you only want to look for files named `textfile.txt` do

```
find test1 -type f -name 'textfile.txt' -print
```

If you want to print the leading slash do

```
find . -type f -printf '/%p\n'
```

For more info have a look [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

Note: If have the above string in a variable, you can trim it like this:

```
string="/home/ABCD/test1/example1/sample1/textfile.txt"
echo "${string#/home/ABCD}"
```

Some more examples of string manipulation [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.` as the starting directory

```
find . -type f -print
```

gives

> ./test1/example1/sample1/textfile.txt

and if you really want a leading slash, use `-printf` for the output

```
find . -type f -printf '/%P\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mindepth` parameter to start looking at one level below the current directory

```
find /home/ABCD/ -mindepth 1 -type f -print
```

Answer (score 0):

This should substitute your current working directory name with a .

```
find . -type f | perl -pne "s#$PWD#.#"
```

So you would get results like:
./test1/example1/sample1/textfile.txt

If you do not want the preceeding ./, use this command instead:

```
find . -type f | perl -pne "s#$PWD/##"
```